# Eclipse Google Cloud SQL connection

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-sql

I am writing a Java MVC web app in Eclipse using Google App Engine.

I would like to know why once I have deployed the app to Google Cloud the Google Cloud MySQL connection stops working. I am not sure how I connect to this once deployed to the cloud but is is clearly not working. I have a connection when running locally?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you have in your app that does not work on the server

Comment: Its the connection to the database that is not working once it has been deployed. Img added to main post

Comment: @GHilton: Putting the code in an image is a bad idea! It is better to paste the text in a block with the delimiter ``` before and after.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of reading, I made a couple of small changes like removing the port number and adding 0.0.0.0/0 into the SQL instance and the app now works really well.

From this, I am now going to close this post.

Many Thanks

Graham

Comment: You can also accept your own answer! That makes it easier for other people to see that the problem is solved.